# How do I switch to a new branch in Git?

Tags: git

I have cloned a Git repository and I would like to switch to a particular branch from the following list (e.g., `branch1, branch2, branch3`).

Should I have to say `git fetch origin branch2`?

How do I know that I have switched to this particular branch on my local repository?

How do I switch to say 'branch3' from 'branch2'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent versions of git have enough DWIM ("Do What I Mean!") logic to understand you just doing:

```
git checkout branch1
```

... in that situtation.  That will work if there is no local branch called `branch1`, and there's only one remote-tracking branch that ends with `branch1` - in that case it's equivalent to the longer:

```
git checkout --track -b branch1 origin/branch1
```

... which should work in every circumstance.

---

I realize that I missed answering some of your later questions.  git stores the state of the branches from the `origin` repository in so-called "remote-tracking branches" - these are the ones that look like `origin/master`, `origin/branch1`, `origin/branch2`, etc.  If you want to update all of these from `origin` just use:

```
git fetch origin
```

To see all of your remote-tracking branches, you can use:

```
git branch -r
```

The meaning of the full command I quoted above:

```
git checkout --track -b branch1 origin/branch1
```

... is:

- create and switch to a new branch called `branch1` (the `checkout -b branch1` bit)
- start it at `origin/branch1` (i.e. base it on the lastest cached state of `branch1` from `origin`)
- and mark `origin/branch1` as being "upstream" of `branch1` in your git config (the `--track` bit, although that's actually implied if the start point is a remote-tracking branch)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to switch to the remote branch. If you just cloned the repository then there should be a default remote called `origin` (you can view your remote repositories via `git remote -v`).

To switch (or check out) a remote branch: `git checkout -t origin/BRANCH_NAME`. This says you want to change your [working directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html) contents to the remote branch `BRANCH_NAME` associated with the remote pointed to by `origin`. This will create something called a "tracking branch" which will set up a local branch to mirror the remote branch.

To check out what branch you're on, type: `git branch`. To switch back to *master* at any time, simply do a `git checkout master`.